# Could not install package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 60.1142.1'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nuget, nuget-package

i have updated most of the packages of xamarin. and also update all the packages related to Map.

but some of the packages can't update. and i got error like below one.

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 60.1142.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.*

and, i have tried with many ways to resolve this above issue. 
tried update Android SDK. 
tried with update visual studio for Xamarin.

but didn't get any solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried changing your Android project Target to v8.x and then installing the package?

Comment: To clarify Nick's point above, ensure it's the TargetFrameworkVersion and not targetSdkVersion.

Comment: change your project to target 7.1 or above then you will be able to install this NuGet package